# rspec passing in both cases - is there any difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have two tests running in rspec and they both seem to make my code pass. Is there any difference between them?

I wouldn't expect the second example to pass my tests since it is not stubbing anything out.

Example 1

```
Lead.stub(:find_or_initialize_by).and_return(lead)
expect(lead).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by).with(contact_id: contact_id, presentation_id: presentation_id)
```

Example 2

```
expect(Lead).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by).with(contact_id: contact_id, presentation_id: presentation_id).and_return(lead)
```

Comment: I cant see how this can be true: `expect(lead).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by)`: `lead` is supposed to be an instance and you call a class mehod on it

Comment: apologies this was an error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The code your testing must call the find_or_initialize_by method with the parameters you list, which is why both of your tests will pass.

When you stub the method that just means that ActiveRecord's find_or_initialize_by method won't actually get invoked. It won't perform a SQL query against the database to look for the record and it won't create a record in the database if one doesn't exist.

If you wanted to make your first test fail you could say

```
expect(Lead.where(contact_id: contact_id, presentation_id: presentation_id)).to exist
```

That will fail because find_or_initialize_by is stubbed in the first example so its effect (creating the record) doesn't actually occur, then when you go to look for the record it doesn't actually exist so the test fails

That probably isn't a valuable test though, I'd suggest getting a book about testing with rspec so you can deepen your understanding about what types of scenarios are valuable to test